# An array in an equation with curly braces in both sides

Tags: equations, align, arrays

I am trying to generate the following equation:
[image]

I am working with an old file (I have not written it) that already has the following code for this equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv\left\{\all\begin{aligned}
0,\quad
\text{if}\;x\ne 0\\
\infty,\quad
\text{if}\; x=0
\end{aligned}\right\}\quad
\text{with}\quad\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\;dx=1.
\end{equation}
```

But this code doesn't work. Do you know what is wrong with that?

Comment: After removing the `\all` in the second line, your code seems to produce the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare four ways to get the result.

The alignment with the original code happens essentially by chance and needs visual formatting (additions of `\quad` and `\;`).

With `Bmatrix` the alignment is again by chance (the second column items have the same width).

With `cases`, adding `\left.` and `\right.`, a bigger space after `\equiv` is used.

The best, in my opinion, is to use `\left\{` and `\right\}`, with a nested `aligned` so you can clearly state the desired left alignment of both columns.

In any case, it should be `\text{if $x=0$}`, so no awkward explicit `\;` is needed (which is not a normal interword space). Also `\,` should precede `dx`, not `\;`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Original without \texttt{\string\all}}
\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv\left\{\begin{aligned}
0,\quad
\text{if}\;x\ne 0\\
\infty,\quad
\text{if}\; x=0
\end{aligned}\right\}\quad
\text{with}\quad\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\;dx=1.
\end{equation}  

\subsubsection*{With \texttt{Bmatrix}}
\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv
\begin{Bmatrix}
0,      & \text{if $x\ne 0$} \\
\infty, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{Bmatrix}
\quad\text{with}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\,dx=1.
\end{equation}

\subsubsection*{With \texttt{cases}}
\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv
\left.
\begin{cases}
0,      & \text{if $x\ne 0$} \\
\infty, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}\right\}
\quad\text{with}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\,dx=1.
\end{equation}

\subsubsection*{With \texttt{aligned}}
\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&0,      && \text{if $x\ne 0$} \\
&\infty, && \text{if $x=0$}
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\quad\text{with}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\,dx=1.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As @siracusa has already pointed out in a comment, the `\all` directive should be removed. The only other significant change I recommend making to your code is adding `&` alignment points inside the `aligned` environment. (After all, why employ an `algin` environment if no alignment is performed?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0,     \quad&\text{if $x\ne 0$}\\
\infty,\quad&\text{if $x=0$}
\end{aligned}
\right\}\,,
\qquad\text{with }
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! \delta(x)\,dx=1.
\end{equation}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cases` to simplify it a little bit and, of course, remove `\all` as @siracusa said.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv\left.\begin{cases}
0,      & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\
\infty, & \text{if } x = 0 
\end{cases}\right\}, \quad\text{with } \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)\; dx = 1.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain \left. please? I am guessing it is somehow affecting the size of the opening curly bracket?

Comment: The `\left` and `\right` in LaTeX must appear in pairs, each opening `\left` must have its closing `\right` the same as parentheses `()` in programming. In your case you only need the `\right\}` because `cases` inserts its own `\left\{`, so you must add a "virtual" `\left.` just to balance the closing `\right\}`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably the `Bmatrix` environment.

Unrelated: I took the opportunity to improve the spacing in the integral.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\delta(x)\equiv
\begin{Bmatrix}
0, & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\
\infty, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{Bmatrix},
\quad\text{with }\int_{-\infty}^{\mathrlap{+\infty}}\delta(x)\,dx = 1.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using only `array` as another alternative with a basic syntax. I have also used double `\!\!` negative space, before and after to have the two bracket more closer. See the figure and the MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\delta(x)\equiv
  \Biggl\{
  \begin{array}{@{}cl@{}}
      0,      & \text{ if $x \ne 0$}  \\
      \infty, & \text{ if $x = 0$} 
  \end{array}
  \Biggr\},
\quad\text{with}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)dx=1.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your preciuous suggestion. My always best regards. You are free to edit my answer if you prefer. :-) I have understood all :-)